# Is there a library that implements a fast maximum rank correlation estimator?

Tags: r, estimation, algorithms, python

I'm looking for an implementation of a fast maximum rank correlation (MRC) estimator. This will be applied to large-ish sparse matrices (~100,000 by 10,000) in a text-mining application.

I'm working in python and R, so it would be nice to find something in those languages. Failing that, I could probably convert code from some other language.

Any suggestions?

Quick note: the best algorithm I've seen described is in [Abrevaya (1999)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6V84-3W7XC0R-4&_user=99318&_coverDate=03%2F01%2F1999&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=gateway&_origin=gateway&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1715406837&_rerunOrigin=scholar.google&_acct=C000007678&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=99318&md5=2818ab10a7b249b05d8a0d0a24c2ff82&searchtype=a), which runs in $nlog(n)$ time.  [Wang (2007)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6V8V-4M813VJ-1&_user=99318&_coverDate=03%2F01%2F2007&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=gateway&_origin=gateway&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1715396891&_rerunOrigin=scholar.google&_acct=C000007678&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=99318&md5=ed8045c282ad6ba5635207366e765e53&searchtype=a) has an "IMO" algorithm that he claims runs in $n^2log(n)$ -- much worse.

Note: I've [cross-posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636093/is-there-a-library-that-implements-a-fast-maximum-rank-correlation-estimator) this question on stackoverflow because I'm not sure which community is the right place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha.  It [looks like](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1308339) this is an unsolved problem in applied statistics.  The best MRC estimators execute in $n^2log(n)$ time or worse, so of course no code is available.