# routines for MRC estimator

Tags: r, classification, references

The Maximum Rank Correlation estimator is the vector that maximizes the Mann Whitney statistic: given vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_m$ and $y_1,\ldots,y_n$, the estimator is the $\beta$ maximizing $\sum_i\sum_j 1(\beta^t x < \beta^t y)$. According to [this old post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/9527/138422), the fastest estimators run in $n^2\log(n)$ time. I still need to compute this estimator, is there code available, or what is the naive algorithm?

The post cites a paper, Wang 2008, but that paper says it need to not get the actual maximum: "the [Nelder-Mead] algorithm and the proposed IMO algorithm share one common limitation. That is there exists no solid theory, which can guarantee the maximizer identified
by either of them is indeed the global maximizer. In fact, they are very likely to be just a local maximizer."

Comment: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/53124/5038